# Java else if and else not working when using Scanner under while loop

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Whenever I run the following code, the if statement that asks for yes/y works when run, however, the else if and else statements don't work. When I try typing in n, no, or anything else, it just stays there. No reaction, no crashes, just sticks there. Anyways here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] items;
    double[] cost;
    int[] quantity;
    double[] totalItemCost;
    int amountOfItems;
    double totalCost = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println("Welcome to The TC corner market, this is an automated cashier program to check out your items.\n");
        System.out.println("May we proceed? y/n");
        if (input.next().equals("y") || input.next().equals("yes")) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println("Okay, let's proceed.");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println("How many items will you be checking out?");
            amountOfItems = input.nextInt();
            items = new String[amountOfItems];
            cost = new double[amountOfItems];
            quantity = new int[amountOfItems];
            totalItemCost = new double[amountOfItems];

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < amountOfItems; i++) {
                System.out.println("\nWhat is the name of the item?");
                items[i] = input.next();
                System.out.println("What is the cost of the item?");
                cost[i] = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("What is the quantity of the item you are purchasing?");
                quantity[i] = input.nextInt();
                totalItemCost[i] = cost[i] * quantity[i];
                System.out.printf("Item:\t\tCost:\t\tQuantity:\t\tTotal Item Cost:\n%s\t\t%.2f\t\t%d\t\t\t\t%.2f", items[i], cost[i], quantity[i], totalItemCost[i]);
                totalCost = totalCost + cost[i];
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println("\n\nYour Checkout Cart:\n");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println("Items:\t\tCost:\t\tQuantity:\t\tTotal Item Cost:\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < amountOfItems; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%s\t\t%.2f\t\t%d\t\t\t\t%.2f\n", items[j], cost[j], quantity[j], totalItemCost[j]);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.printf("\nYour total: %.2f", totalCost);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println("\n\nThank you for checking out with The TC corner market! This program will restart in 10 seconds.");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        } else if (input.next().equals("n") || input.next().equals("no")) {
            System.out.println("In that case, please proceed to return your items back to the store");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            break;
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println("Invalid Answer");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing many things, like changing it from else if to regular if, adding the break (which I now have in my code I am posting above), and just completely removing the else statement and turning the else if to else. None of them worked though.

Comment: Your mistake in if statements `input.next().equals("y") || input.next().equals("yes")` ... For break you program you should type in console `n n n`.  If you type in console `n` after your first check `input.next().equals("y")` scanner will be empty - that why you not came to the second check `equals("yes")` and second if-else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the value of `input.next()` in a variable before your `if` condition.

Something like this:

```
String next = input.next();
```

And replace all subsequent `input.next()` with `next`.

---

**Explanation:**

The reason it's not working is that with each `input.next()` it waits for a new string input.

Let's say you input: `"n"`

In the first `if` condition it will be compared with `"y"` which it won't match, the next `input.next()` will try to retake input, that's why it isn't showing anything because it's waiting for your input.